# Espresso how to assert intent data

Tags: android, android-intent, android-espresso

This is my intent:

> -Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=smsto:xxxxxxx@xxxxx.xxx (has extras) } handling packages:[[com.android.messaging]],
>   extras:[Bundle[{sms_body=myText}]])

How matcher should look like in order to assert data like this:

> dat=smsto:xxxxxxx@xxxxx.xxx

For example this won't work:

```
intented(hasData("xxxxxxx@xxxxx.xxx");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
intented(hasData(Uri.parse("smsto:xxxxxxx@xxxxx.xxx"));
```

It should work !

(Replace 'xxx's with actual characters.)

Comment: It should have worked, I have a similar working example here : https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/blob/master/ui/espresso/IntentsBasicSample/app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/android/testing/espresso/BasicSample/DialerActivityTest.java#L113

Comment: Okay problem was that "x" represents letters and I was inserting xxxxxx into `intented(hasData(Uri.parse("smsto:xxxxxxx@xxxxx.xxx"));` When I did something like `intented(hasData(Uri.parse("smsto:mymail@something.com"));` then it worked.

Comment: That was obviously expected, I thought you are doing that and in order to not reveal here, you were setting 'xxx' values. If it solved your problem, plz accept the answer and upvote it, so that others can benefit.